# Box in css gets colored in a square shape instead of skewed

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website. I'm coloring the menu items, but when coloring in the top left image (background color), it gets colored in square.

I would like to have it colored in skewed, so that it follows the black outline.

A screenshot of the problem and some of the html:

[image]

Is there anything I could do to make this work?

The html code of the bar:

```
 <div class="iwgh2-bar">
   <div class="iw2-layout iw2-default-breakpoint">
     <div class="iw2-wrapper iw2-default-margin">
       <div class="iw2-inner-wrapper">
         <div class="iwgh2-navigation">
           <a class="iw2-branded" href="https://www.vlaanderen.be/nl" target="_self">
             <div class="iwgh2-branding-logo"></div>
             <span>Vlaanderen</span>
           </a>
           <div class="iw2-menu iw2-menu-has-items" data-show-menu-help="Toon navigatie menu" data-hide-menu-help="Verberg navigatie menu">
             <div class="iwgh2-navigation-menu-toggle-wrapper">
               <div class="iwgh2-navigation-menu-toggle-animation-wrapper" style="">
                 <a class="iwgh2-navigation-menu-site" style="" href="http://binnenland.vlaanderen.be">Agentschap Binnenlands Bestuur</a>
                 <a class="iwgh2-navigation-menu-breadcrumb" style="" href="http://www.gelijkekansen.be">Gelijke Kansen</a>
                 <a class="iwgh2-navigation-menu-toggle iw2-exclude-from-outbound-link-tracking" href="javascript:;" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="64ed92f1-fece-e61f-2d15-0af8093d9040" aria-controls="64ed92f1-fece-e61f-2d15-0af8093d9040"><span class="iw2-visually-hidden iw2-help-text"> Toon navigatie menu </span></a>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="iwgh2-flyout-wrapper iw2-window-closed" style="display: none; left: 375.4px;" tabindex="-1" id="64ed92f1-fece-e61f-2d15-0af8093d9040">
               <div class="iwgh2-search iw2-hidden" role="search">

                 <div class="iwgh2-form-label">
                   <label for="iwgh2-search-field">Zoeken</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="iwgh2-form-textfield">
                   <input id="iwgh2-search-field" class="iwgh2-search-field iwgh2-form-text" name="query" type="search">
                 </div>
                 <div class="iwgh2-form-actions">
                   <div class="iwgh2-form-action">
                     <div class="iwgh2-form-button">
                       <input class="iwgh2-form-submit" name="op" value="" type="submit">
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>

               </div>
               <ul class="iw2-menu-items" tabindex="-1">
                 <li class="iw2-menu-item"><a class="iw2-menu-item-wrapper" href="http://lokaalbestuur.vlaanderen.be" target="_self">Lokaal Bestuur</a></li>
                 <li class="iw2-menu-item"><a class="iw2-menu-item-wrapper" href="http://www.thuisindestad.be" target="_self">Vlaams Stedenbeleid</a></li>
                 <li class="iw2-menu-item"><a class="iw2-menu-item-wrapper" href="http://integratiebeleid.vlaanderen.be" target="_self">Integratie en Inburgering</a></li>
                 <li class="iw2-menu-item"><a class="iw2-menu-item-wrapper" href="http://www.vlaamserand.be" target="_self">Beleid Vlaamse Rand</a></li>
                 <li class="iw2-menu-item"><a class="iw2-menu-item-wrapper" href="http://brussel.vlaanderen.be/home.html" target="_self">Beleid Brussel</a></li>
               </ul>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="iwgh2-extensions">
           <div class="iwgh2-extension-contact" data-show-menu-help="Toon menu" data-hide-menu-help="Verberg menu">
             <a class="iwgh2-extension-contact-toggle iw2-exclude-from-outbound-link-tracking" href="http://www.gelijkekansen.be/Praktisch/Contact.aspx" target="_self" aria-owns="906864c8-0db7-9b35-52ce-143b0e4d962a" aria-controls="906864c8-0db7-9b35-52ce-143b0e4d962a" aria-expanded="false"><span class="iw2-visually-hidden iw2-help-text"> Toon menu </span>Contacteer ons</a>
             <div class="iwgh2-extension-contact-wrapper iwgh2-flyout-wrapper">
               <div class="iwgh2-contact-menu iw2-window-closed iw2-menu-has-items" style="display:none;" tabindex="-1" id="906864c8-0db7-9b35-52ce-143b0e4d962a">
                 <div class="iwgh2-contact-menu-header">
                   <span class="iw2-menu-item-title">Gelijke kansen</span>
                 </div>
                 <ul class="iw2-menu-items">
                   <li class="iw2-menu-item iw2-contact-section-entry iw2-contact-section-entry-icon-link iw2-contact-section-entry-type-link"><a class="iw2-menu-item-wrapper" href="http://www.gelijkekansen.be/Praktisch/Contact.aspx" target="_self"><span class="iw2-menu-item-title">Contacteer ons</span>
                       <div class="iw2-menu-item-description"></div>
                     </a></li>
                   <li class="iw2-menu-item iw2-contact-section-entry iw2-contact-section-entry-icon-link iw2-contact-section-entry-type-link"><a class="iw2-menu-item-wrapper" href="http://binnenland.vlaanderen.be/klachten" target="_self"><span class="iw2-menu-item-title">Klachten</span>
                       <div class="iw2-menu-item-description">Waar kan ik terecht met een klacht?</div>
                     </a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="iwgh2-windows">
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.iwgh2.iwgh2-redesign .iwgh2-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbd2da;
}

.iwgh2.iwgh2-redesign.iwgh2-default-margin .iw2-layout .iw2-wrapper.iw2-default-margin {
  padding: 0;
}

.iwgh2-bar .iw2-wrapper {
  *zoom: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.iw2-wrapper .iw2-inner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.iwgh2-navigation {
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.iwgh2.iwgh2-redesign .iwgh2-navigation>a {
  color: #333332;
  font-size: 1.1875em;
  line-height: 2.31579em;
  text-transform: none;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.iwgh2.iwgh2-redesign.iwgh2-redesign-alt .iwgh2-branding-logo {
  position: relative;
  width: 47px;
  background-color: #FFE507;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.iwgh2 .iw2-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: relative;
}

.iwgh2.iwgh2-redesign.iwgh2-default-margin .iw2-layout {
  max-width: none;
}

.iwgh2-bar .iw2-layout {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Don't just link an image, post your code here so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please add your code so we can check what is going wrong

Comment: edit: html and css added

Comment: Please take a look at this JS Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tf3x6ybe/) - composed using the code you've published in your question - it doesn't reproduce the problem you describe in the question, or that you show in the image. Can you remove any unnecessary code (please read the "*[mcve]*" guidance) and add whatever is missing so that the code you've shown reproduces the problem, otherwise we're looking through too much code to try and find the issue which is a recipe for an unsatisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle and see if that is what you wanted

```
#trapezoid {
        border-bottom: 100px solid #FFE507;
        border-right: 25px solid transparent;
        height: 0;
        width: 100px;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CaffeinatedCod3r/r7deqakL/

More CSS Shapes : https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/